# Creating a derived class from a base

Tags: c++, qt

I get the following error message:

```
conversion from ‘BaseClass’ to non-scalar type ‘DerivedClass’ requested
```

while compiling something like:

```
AnotherClass response;
DerivedClass message = response.serialize(QString("someStuff"));
```

where I have

```
BaseClass AnotherClass::serialize( const QString& valueName ) const
```

and

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    ...
    DerivedClass &operator=(const BaseClass &other);
}
```

Can someone explain what is wrong here, and more importantly **why**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DerivedClass message = response.serialize(QString("someStuff"));
```

This is *copy-initialization*, not assignment, and `operator=` doesn't even come in play.

You either need a constructor that takes `BaseClass` or write it like this:

```
AnotherClass response;
DerivedClass message;
message = response.serialize(QString("someStuff")); // assignment
```

Comment: Right, I just realized of the = operator. And that it is a matter of copy-initialization rather than assignment. +1

Answer (score 0):

Besides using copy-initialization, not assignment as you think you are, you are also violating the [rule of three/four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

The rule is that if you have *any* of the below, you must have *all* of them (either implemented or deleted using Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE):

1. Destructor
2. Copy Constructor
3. Move Constructor (for C++11)
4. Assignment Operator

For example, suppose you don't want to implement assignment. You should have:

```
class MyClass {
  // private, deleted - compatible with both C++11 and C++98/03.
  MyClass & operator=(const MyClass &) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
public:
  MyClass(const MyClass &);
  MyClass(MyClass &&);
  virtual ~MyClass();
  ...
};
```